# HASHBYTES in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow, md5, oracle-adf, hashbytes

So we found this strange use case where result of function HASHBYTES with MD5 gives different output in COPY Data vs. ADF DataFlow using (MD5 function).

So Copy Data uses (allows) to leverage HASHBYTES(MD5, ), but Azure Data factory (ADF) DataFlow does not allow to use funciton HASHBYTES, instead it has MD5 function in Dynamic function list in Datflow, but output from both Copy Data and DataFlow from ADF is different.

Any thoughts ?

Regards,
Viral

Comment: In copy activity we cannot use hashing. Only in dataflow hashing can be done? Can you provide your sample input and expected result and pipeline image that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) and [ADF expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions), there is no `HASHBYTES` function in ADF expressions or in copy activity. You can see the same here.

[image]

You can use hash functions only in ADF dataflow by using the functions like [`MD5`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#md5) and [`SHA1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#sha1).

[image]

So, use dataflow to achieve your requirement.